# Change data type of single or multiple columns of Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-wrangling

I have a data frame and I want to change data types for different columns. I have made a schema of the data range as I have varied data types in each column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
orders_schema = {
  '?dummy'              :np.int64,  
  '@timestamp'          :np.str,        
  '@version'            :np.int64,  
  'bytes'               :np.int64,  
  'c-geoip'             :np.str,    
  'c-isp'               :np.str,    
  'client'              :np.str,    
  'duration_usec'       :np.int64,  
  'forwarded_for'       :np.str,    
  'gtmcb'               :np.float64,
  'handling'            :np.str,    
  'hit_miss'            :np.str,  
  'host'                :np.str,  
  'method_urlv'         :np.str,    
  'ns__t'               :np.float64, 
  'ns_jspageurl'      :np.str,  
  'ns_referrer'         :np.str,    
  'parsed-useragent'    :np.str,    
  'port'                :np.int64,
  'referer'             :np.str,  
  'remote_user'         :np.str,  
  'request'             :np.str,  
  'nav'                 :np.str,  
  'pp'                  :np.str,  
  'profileid'           :np.float64,
  'source'              :np.str,    
  'titel'               :np.str,    
  'type'                :np.str,    
  'userid'              :np.str,    
  'uuid'                :np.str,    
  'status'              :np.int64,  
  'tags'                :np.str,    
  'time_first_byte'     :np.float64,    
  'topic'               :np.str,    
  'type'                :np.str,    
  'user-agent'          :np.str,  
  'version'             :np.str,    
  'lhost'               :np.str
}
```

However, I don't know how I can apply this schema to an existing data frame. I tried

```
df_2.astype(orders_schema)
KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.'
```

Could you pls suggest me how I can change data types for columns?

Thanks in advance

Comment: kindly share sample data

Answer (score 0):

You can only provide column names in the keys of order_schema. Are all those column names

Comment: well indeed they are all column names and desires data types for those columns

Comment: I think any one of the column name is not matching with what you have provided in the dictionary as this is what the error is saying. Can u please provide the ss or check the column names again

Comment: well double checked nothing wrong with columns name

Comment: Can u share ss if possible